# Calling an application from a perl script

Tags: perl

I would like to call an application from a perl script using the 'system' command. However, the application is placed in a separate directory. How can I call the application from that directory in my perl script. Can I use "require"?

Answer (score 3):

You can just change directory if you want to run the application in the directory where the application resides. See the `chdir` command in `perlfunc`.

Otherwise, just add the path like this:

```
system('/path/to/the/application');
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `require` doesn't work -- `require` is used to pull in other perl files, once. If, of course, the file you'd like to call to *is* a perl program ... well, it's probably better to factor out the parts you'd like to be shared between the two programs, rather than `require`ing it, or to simply treat it as a black box anyway if you don't want to do that.

To call an executable which is neither in the search path -- simply being in the same directory is not sufficient! -- supply the full path to, e.g. `system`, `exec`, &c.. For system, the preferred forms would be:

```
system { '/path/to/executable' } 'argument 0 (i.e. $0) supplied to program', 'argument 1 (equivalent to $ARGV[0])', ...;
```

or

```
# $path = ...
system $path 'arg 0', 'arg 1', ...;
```

or

```
# $path = ...
system $path @args;
```

Of course, it is good form to check the result of each system call in case of errors.

Note the use of indirect-object (i.e. with an argument passed without comma, like the fh for a print or such) `system` in every case! Unless you know very well what you're doing and why, it's hard to recommend risk using the one-argument form of `system`, because it subjects your input to the whims of shell preprocessing.

Consult `perldoc -fsystem` and `perldoc -fexec` for more detail.